# Draw a stretched and rotated image on TCanvas

Tags: delphi

i am trying to draw a rotated bitmap on a TImage canvas at some specified points, what i tried so far is i rotated the bitmap and then used stretched draw but i am not getting the results i want, the scenario goes like this

- I map 4 points on a TImage canvas with mouse clicks and get its angle, the angle can be 0, 45, 90 anything, something like in the image i have attached

[image: This Image]

- Now what i need is to draw another bitmap rotated and stretched on these points, i am having a hard time figuring this thing out

Regards

Comment: You may want to see `SetWorldTransform`.

Comment: If you choose all 4 points arbitrarily, you may need perspective transformation, not affine one.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, when stars was brighter and girls was younger, i wrote this code for unknown reason. It is VCL compatible, but can be adopter in order to be used in both VCL/FMX. It is simple class to draw arbitrary rectangle from bitmap to arbitrary rectangle at destination DC (so it could be bitmap or something else). It can paint destination picture with bilinear interpolation, then result looks not so ugly as with simple stretching. Maybe it can be useful for someone.

```
unit uBMPUtils;

interface

uses
  windows, graphics, math, sysutils;

type
  PIntegers = ^TIntegers;
  TIntegers = array[0..high(integer) div sizeof(integer) - 16] of integer;

  TDrawLine = procedure(    pixelSize                      : integer;
                        var src;
                            srcLineAdd                     : integer;
                            src_x1, src_y1, src_x2, src_y2 : integer;
                        var dst;
                            dstLen                         : integer) of object;

  TDrawMode = (dmSimple, dmBilinear);
  TBitmapDrawer = class
  protected
    tmp          : TBitmap;
    koefs        : array[0..4096*4-1] of integer;   // addr(Ux, Vy) = 4 * ( (trunc(Ux*16) << 6) + trunc(Vy*16) )
    calculated   : boolean;
    DrawModeFlag : TDrawMode;
    DrawLine     : TDrawLine;

    procedure   precalculate;                // precalculate koefs for fast bilinear interpolation

    procedure   drawLineSimple(    pixelSize                      : integer;
                               var src;
                                   srcLineAdd                     : integer;
                                   src_x1, src_y1, src_x2, src_y2 : integer;
                               var dst;
                                   dstLen                         : integer);

    procedure   drawLineBilinear(    pixelSize                      : integer;
                                 var src;
                                     srcLineAdd                     : integer;
                                     src_x1, src_y1, src_x2, src_y2 : integer;
                                 var dst;
                                     dstLen                         : integer);
    procedure   setDrawMode(m : TDrawMode);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor  Destroy; override;

    procedure   DrawTriangle(src              : TBitmap;       // source bitmap (pf24 or pf32!)
                             dst_dc           : cardinal;      // destination DC
                             dstRect          : TRect;         // limiting rect for output
                             A1, A2, A3,                       // arbitrary rectange at Src bitmap
                             B1, B2, B3       : TPoint);       // arbitrary rectange at DST_DC device

    procedure   DrawRectangle(src              : TBitmap;      // source bitmap (pf24 or pf32!)
                              dst_dc           : cardinal;     // destination DC
                              dstRect          : TRect;        // limiting rect for output
                              A1, A2, A3, A4,                  // arbitrary rectange at Src bitmap
                              B1, B2, B3, B4   : TPoint);      // arbitrary rectange at DST_DC device

    property DrawMode: TDrawMode read DrawModeFlag write setDrawMode; // Default: dmBilinear
  end;

implementation

function HorAtLine(var x : integer; y, x1,y1,x2,y2 : integer):boolean;
begin
  if y1 = y2 then result := false else
    begin
      result := (y >= y1) and (y <= y2) or (y >= y2) and (y <= y1);
      if result then x := x1 + (x2 - x1) * (y - y1) div (y2 - y1);
    end;
end;

procedure LineProportion(var src_x, src_y                   : integer;
                             src_x1, src_y1, src_x2, src_y2 : integer;
                             dst_x, dst_y                   : integer;
                             dst_x1, dst_y1, dst_x2, dst_y2 : integer);
begin
  if abs(dst_x2 - dst_x1) > abs(dst_y2 - dst_y1) then begin // proportions form Y
    src_x := src_x1 + (src_x2 - src_x1) * (dst_x - dst_x1) div (dst_x2 - dst_x1);
    src_y := src_y1 + (src_y2 - src_y1) * (dst_x - dst_x1) div (dst_x2 - dst_x1);
  end else begin
    src_x := src_x1 + (src_x2 - src_x1) * (dst_y - dst_y1) div (dst_y2 - dst_y1);
    src_y := src_y1 + (src_y2 - src_y1) * (dst_y - dst_y1) div (dst_y2 - dst_y1);
  end;
end;

// ---------------------------------------------- TBitmapDrawer --------------------------------------------------------

procedure TBitmapDrawer.precalculate;
var
  n, u, v             : integer;
  Uf, Vf, k1,k2,k3,k4 : double;
begin
  calculated := true;
  for V := 0 to 63 do
    for U := 0 to 63 do
      begin
        Uf := U / 64;
        Vf := V / 64;
        k1 := (1 - Uf) * (1 - Vf);
        k2 :=      Uf  * (1 - Vf);
        k3 := (1 - Uf) *      Vf;
        k4 :=      Uf  *      Vf;
        n          := ((U shl 6) + V) * 4;
        koefs[n]   := trunc(k1*65536);
        koefs[n+1] := trunc(k2*65536);
        koefs[n+2] := trunc(k3*65536);
        koefs[n+3] := trunc(k4*65536);
      end;
end;

constructor TBitmapDrawer.create;
begin
  inherited create;
  tmp        := TBitmap.create;
  tmp.Height := 1;
  drawMode   := dmBilinear;
  precalculate;
end;

destructor TBitmapDrawer.Destroy;
begin
  FreeandNil(tmp);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBitmapDrawer.DrawRectangle(src              : TBitmap;
                                      dst_dc           : cardinal;
                                      dstRect          : TRect;
                                      A1, A2, A3, A4,
                                      B1, B2, B3, B4   : TPoint);
begin
  DrawTriangle(src, dst_dc, dstRect, A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3);
  DrawTriangle(src, dst_dc, dstRect, A1, A3, A4, B1, B3, B4);
end;

procedure TBitmapDrawer.DrawTriangle(src              : TBitmap;
                                     dst_dc           : cardinal;
                                     dstRect          : TRect;
                                     A1, A2, A3,
                                     B1, B2, B3       : TPoint);
var
  pixelSize, srcAdd, left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y: integer;
  minx, maxx, x, y, top, bottom : integer;
  pb : pointer;
begin
  if src.height > 1 then srcAdd := integer(PAnsiChar(src.scanline[1]) - PAnsiChar(src.scanline[0])) else srcAdd := 0;
  top    := min(min(b1.y, b2.y), b3.y);
  bottom := max(max(b1.y, b2.y), b3.y);
  if (top > dstRect.Bottom) or (bottom < dstRect.Top) then exit;
  if top    < dstRect.Top    then top    := dstRect.Top;
  if bottom > dstRect.Bottom then bottom := dstRect.Bottom;
  case src.pixelFormat of
    pf24bit : pixelsize := 3;
    pf32bit : pixelsize := 4;
    else raise exception.create('Error');
  end;
  if tmp.PixelFormat <> src.PixelFormat then tmp.PixelFormat := src.PixelFormat;
  y             := max(max(b1.X, b2.x), b3.x) - min(min(b1.X, b2.x), b3.x) + 1;
  if (tmp.Width < y) then tmp.Width := y;
  pb            := tmp.scanline[0];
  for y := top to bottom do // Y at destination picture
    begin
      minx := high(integer);
      maxx := low(integer);

      if HorAtLine(x,y, b1.X, b1.Y, b2.x, b2.Y) then
        begin
          if x < minx then begin
            minx := x;
            LineProportion(left_x, left_y,   a1.X, a1.Y, a2.x, a2.Y,       x,y,   b1.X, b1.Y, b2.X, b2.Y);
          end;
          if x > maxx then begin
            LineProportion(right_x, right_y,   a1.X, a1.Y, a2.x, a2.Y,       x,y,   b1.X, b1.Y, b2.X, b2.Y);
            maxx := x;
          end;
        end;

      if HorAtLine(x,y, b2.X, b2.Y, b3.x, b3.Y) then
        begin
          if x < minx then begin
            minx := x;
            LineProportion(left_x, left_y,   a2.X, a2.Y, a3.x, a3.Y,       x,y,   b2.X, b2.Y, b3.X, b3.Y);
          end;
          if x > maxx then begin
            LineProportion(right_x, right_y,   a2.X, a2.Y, a3.x, a3.Y,       x,y,   b2.X, b2.Y, b3.X, b3.Y);
            maxx := x;
          end;
        end;

      if HorAtLine(x,y, b3.X, b3.Y, b1.x, b1.Y) then
        begin
          if x < minx then begin
            minx := x;
            LineProportion(left_x, left_y,   a3.X, a3.Y, a1.x, a1.Y,       x,y,   b3.X, b3.Y, b1.X, b1.Y);
          end;
          if x > maxx then begin
            LineProportion(right_x, right_y,   a3.X, a3.Y, a1.x, a1.Y,       x,y,   b3.X, b3.Y, b1.X, b1.Y);
            maxx := x;
          end;
        end;

      if minx > maxx then continue;
      // destination line (minx, y) - (maxx, y) - now we can find it at source picture
      drawLine(pixelSize, src.ScanLine[0]^, srcAdd, left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y, pb^, maxx - minx + 1);
      bitblt(dst_dc, minx, y,  maxx-minx+1, 1, tmp.Canvas.Handle, 0,0, srccopy);
    end;
end;

procedure TBitmapDrawer.drawLineSimple(    pixelSize                      : integer;
                                       var src;
                                           srcLineAdd                     : integer;
                                           src_x1, src_y1, src_x2, src_y2 : integer;
                                       var dst;
                                           dstLen                         : integer);
var
  dst_ptr   : PAnsiChar;
  i, px, py : integer;
begin
  dst_ptr := @dst;
  px      := (src_x2 - src_x1) * 65536 div dstLen;
  py      := (src_y2 - src_y1) * 65536 div dstLen;
  src_x1  := src_x1 * 65536;
  src_y1  := src_y1 * 65536;
  for i := 0 to dstLen - 1 do
    begin
      pinteger(dst_ptr)^ := pinteger( PAnsiChar(@src) +
                                      ((src_y1 + i * py) shr 16) * srcLineAdd +
                                      ((src_x1 + i * px) shr 16) * pixelSize
                                    )^;
      inc(dst_ptr, pixelSize);
    end;
end;

procedure TBitmapDrawer.drawLineBilinear(    pixelSize                      : integer;
                                         var src;
                                             srcLineAdd                     : integer;
                                             src_x1, src_y1, src_x2, src_y2 : integer;
                                         var dst;
                                             dstLen                         : integer);
var
  src_ptr, dst_ptr     : PAnsiChar;
  u,v,Uf,Vf            : integer;
  i                    : integer;
  k                    : PIntegers;
  c1,c2,c3,c4          : TColor;
begin
  dst_ptr := @dst;
  for i := 0 to dstLen - 1 do
    begin
      u       := src_x1 + i * (src_x2 - src_x1) div dstLen;
      v       := src_y1 + i * (src_y2 - src_y1) div dstLen;
      Uf      := (src_x1 + i * (src_x2 - src_x1) * 64 div dstLen) and $3f;
      Vf      := (src_y1 + i * (src_y2 - src_y1) * 64 div dstLen) and $3f;
      k       := @koefs[4*((Uf shl 6) + Vf)];
      src_ptr := PAnsiChar(@src) + v * srcLineAdd + u * pixelSize;
      c1      := pinteger(src_ptr)^;
      c2      := pinteger(src_ptr + 4)^;
      c3      := pinteger(src_ptr + srcLineAdd)^;
      c4      := pinteger(src_ptr + srcLineAdd + 4)^;

      pinteger(dst_ptr)^ :=
              ( (c1 and $FF)*k[0] shr 16 +
                (c2 and $FF)*k[1] shr 16 +
                (c3 and $FF)*k[2] shr 16 +
                (c4 and $FF)*k[3] shr 16 )
            or
              ( ((c1 shr 8) and $FF)*k[0] shr 16 +
                ((c2 shr 8) and $FF)*k[1] shr 16 +
                ((c3 shr 8) and $FF)*k[2] shr 16 +
                ((c4 shr 8) and $FF)*k[3] shr 16    ) shl 8
            or
              ( ((c1 shr 16) and $FF)*k[0] shr 16 +
                ((c2 shr 16) and $FF)*k[1] shr 16 +
                ((c3 shr 16) and $FF)*k[2] shr 16 +
                ((c4 shr 16) and $FF)*k[3] shr 16   ) shl 16
            or $02000000;

      inc(dst_ptr, pixelSize);
    end;
end;

procedure TBitmapDrawer.setDrawMode(m: TDrawMode);
begin
  drawModeFlag := m;
  case drawModeFlag of
    dmSimple   : drawLine := drawLineSimple;
    dmBilinear : drawLine := drawLineBilinear;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, it works ok with a regular area, but with an irregular area the image area overlaps eachother...

Comment: @Junaid Could you provide example of input parameters when it fails? Code is old, but i checked small demo i have, demo itself quite complex (picture splitted to many pieces to simulate kind of "flag in the wind" effect) and it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the desired output using Projective transformation method in Graphics32 http://graphics32.org/wiki/